# Push Excel data into ASPX form using excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I need to automate a process by push excel data into fields in an ASPX form.

This is the "inspect element" of the ASPX form:

```
<form name="form1" id="form1" action="./Main.aspx" encType="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" method="post">
   <table width="100%" border="0" cellSpacing="0" cellPadding="0">
      <tr>
         <td height="50">
            <input name="clusterName" id="clusterNameID" maxLength="100"></input>
         </td>
         <td height="50">
            <input name="submitBtn" id="submitBtnID" onclick="return checkAdd();" type="submit" value="Add"></input>
         </td>
      </tr>
```

**let me be clear on what I need: I need to push data from excel cell "a1" into the txtField "clusterName" & after that invoke the submitBtn to auto submit the form.** 
I have searched high & low but there is few documentation of how this can be done on an .aspx form... Most documentation are only for .html
Can any kind souls out there help me?